# OS X hotkeys activating with just a left mouse click

Tags: macos, mouse-click

In Firefox, if I click with the mouse on a link, it opens in a new tab. On the desktop when I try and click on a shortcut from my desktop, it shows me where the file is in the applications folder.

This happens on both my keyboards. Why does this happen?

Also, are there any more details I can give to help?

Comment: *when I try and click on a shortcut from my desktop, it shows me where the file is in the applications folder* – Does it really just reveal the file in another Finder window? Do you have any tools installed that modify mouse/keyboard behavior? Has this ever been that way or do you remember when it started? Does it work on another user profile?

Comment: @slhck It's Command-click behavior on the Dock.

Comment: @DanielBeck Uh, okay. The *dock* is not the *desktop* … *that* would explain it.

Answer (score 1):

Your <kbd>Command</kbd> key is stuck programmatically by e.g. running `key down command` in AppleScript.

If you didn't program, try pressing it repeatedly, and make sure the keyboard is clean.

Try to log out and back in. This will reset the relevant UI state.

---

If you really programmed it in AppleScript, prepare by create a *Service* in *Automator* that receives *no input* in *any application* and has the following *Run AppleScript* action:

```
tell application "System Events"
    key up command
    key up option
    key up control
    key up shift
end tell
```

This will reset all modifier keys' states. Save to make it available in any application's *Service* submenu of the application menu.

Comment: It happens on both of the OP's keyboards though.

Comment: @slhck True. Check out my edit, if you do some GUI scripting in AppleScript it might help you as well. The countless times I had to et creative in resetting a modifier key...

Comment: I haven't used any AppleScript.

Comment: @PigHead AppleScript can be run from applications as well. Does this problem appear regularly? Did you try to log out and back in?

Comment: Yes, I restarted the computer as well.

Comment: @PigHead Did you bury a wireless keyboard under a stack of stuff somewhere?